# Can't comment on account newly created

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)
>   [How do I add a comment to an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/how-do-i-add-a-comment-to-an-answer)

I cannot insert a comment on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24690/30071 . I realise that this is probably due to my reputation (1) on this particular Stack Exchange site, but after reading

- [How do I add a comment to an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23212/203560),
- [the faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [the privileges page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges)
- [the "comment" privilege page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment)

This leads to me no confirmation of this, nor what reputation I have to amass to do this (TBH, I expected more from such a great site). Why is this info not really easy to find, like most other things?

I have two suggestions:

1. Think about where this info is best put, to be easily accessible (Not sure where the cited text in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23212/203560 went also).
2. Perhaps it would be better to put a single line of text where the comment button normally is, for users like me (currently), stating you cannot post due to reputation, and link to the page with more info.

Comment: When you mouse-over the `comment everywhere` privilege, it tells you you need 50 points. When you click on the link, it tells you at the top that you require 50 points, unless you already passed that point.

Comment: Or you could just post your comment as an answer.  There's a good chance that the rep-hungry review zombies will up-vote your answer enough to thwart efforts to close your post by a bunch of people who've long forgotten what it's like to be a newbie. Either way, you'll get your point made.

Comment: Martijn - As I have commented in the past, I don't think that the sidebar should be used for primary content. As such, I did completely miss this. Likewise, I don't think anything more than a comment (as shown inn pictures on the faq page) should be displayed in the alt tag. The accepted comment in my first link is what I expected to see on (Thanks for Brad correcting the base URL to the faq link of this subdomain) the faq, in the main body so cannot be missed.

Comment: @Chris Gerken - Thanks, but my comment to the referenced post was that I am also experiencing this, to give weight to what seems to currently be a unique case. Not really an answer.

Comment: You might be interested in voting for  [Show the “add comment” link also to users who cannot add comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144537/), which corresponds to [what was done with the edit link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138944/151987)

Comment: @BradMace - I do; Voted; Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Of the four pages you claim to have read:

- the first is closed as a duplicate of a question which contains the answer you're looking for
- the third shows how close you are as a percentage (and the exact points needed if you hover over it)
- the fourth says very explicitly in large font at the top of the page:

[image]

Comment: Correction - The first page makes _no_ mention of webapps.stackexchange.com (Unless you count the link in the footer), and I have got this impression that different SE sub sites have different requirements. This may be wrong, but as I wasn't looking in the **sidebar** for content, instead of **navigation**, this wasn't apparent to me. Also, are you serious that **content** is being put in an **alt** tag?

Comment: Getting indignant about things (like the common practice of placing supplementary info in tool tips) doesn't usually lead to constructive discussion. That's also why I removed your "I expected more" comment from the question--it comes across as rather patronizing. There may be useful ways to increase the discoverability of this info, but your suggestions are more likely to get serious consideration if they don't come across as scolding.

Comment: This was not my intention. I often visit this website to find info to solve problems I have, and most of the time to add to problems others have issues with that I have found a solution for, as I hold it in high esteem to be a community that values (what I consider) striving to be the best commonplace resource on the net; to pride themselves on logical / intuitive presentation of this info; etc. Had this been I site I don't value, I probably wouldn't have even commented, let alone held this site to a high standard. Perhaps I am missing out on lots of info on the web, by not checking the tool

Comment: tips, but like you said they should be for supplemental information. The reputation required to comment I don't consider to be as such, nor my current reputation. I think tool tips should be reserved for explanations of details on the page, so those who need it, have it available. e.g., http://i.imgur.com/fIlwj.png / http://i.imgur.com/zqaEN.png. If this single line, and not the point of my feature request, will make it be disregarded, I will live with this, but personally think this community if worse of for it not being considered

Answer (score 3):

You currently have [1 rep point](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/30071/user66001) on WebApp.SE

You need 50 to comment.

As you showed, it is stated in **many places** what the requirements are.

Comment: Thank-you for your slightly nicer comment amanaP lanaC A nalP A nal, but like I have commented on other parts of this question, I wasn't looking in the navigation bar bar for content, nor would I have thought it necessary to hover on something, to see it's alt text, to get anything more than a tip, not primary content.

Answer (score 1):

With 1 reputation you can only comment on your answers and questions. To be able to comment on questions or answers by other people you need at least 50 reputation. It's written in [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: Thanks José Roberto Araújo JúniorJo, I missed the "show more" on the faq page (Thanks for the a href link), probably due to it's similar colour to the picture right above it, and it's proximity to such. I also don't find it intuitive / common to have "show more"'s below anything else but a header.

Comment: Though I am used to the show more comments / add comment on SE sites, think this stands out more around the otherwise white background. Think this question is more about UI design tripping a percentage of the users up. I am sure I am not the first, nor will be the last that will have this issue, so only hope this question will prompt some discussion about how this information is shown for others in the future.